# Native Base Input Refs Not Being Set

Tags: javascript, react-native, reference, native-base

So I'm working with the Native Base `<Input>` tag, trying to set refs to handle "tabbing" through form fields. I've got the following code:

```
<Item floatingLabel>
  <Label style={{ color: "#fff" }}>First Name</Label>
  <Input
    ref={input => {
      this.firstNameRef = input;
    }}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
      this.lastNameRef._root.focus();
    }}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
  />
</Item>

<Item floatingLabel last>
  <Label style={{ color: "#fff" }}>Last Name</Label>
  <Input
    ref={input => {
      this.lastNameRef = input;
    }}
  />
</Item>
```

So essentially, I have 2 `<Input>` tags, both with `ref` set (`this.firstNameRef` and `this.lastNameRef`), but on loading the App, pressing First Name, then pressing "next" on the keyboard I get the following error:

> Cannot read property '_root' of undefined
>   onSubmitEditing
>   *Signup.js:162:26*

It seems that using `<Input>` doesn't actually set any ref values, so `this.lastNameRef` is `null`.

I also tried using React Native's `<TextInput>` element, which does handle setting refs as described above, but still doesn't seem to handle focus after submit (even when removing `._root` from `.focus()` logic).

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Note: Only tested in iOS currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For nativeBase's input component you need to use a `getRef` prop:

```
<Input
  getRef={input => {
    this.lastNameRef = input;
  }}
/>
```

Comment: You are correct; I was just in the process of writing a self-answer (saw the post here https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/70#issuecomment-288434297)

Comment: `._root` seems to work fine in my testing; didn't see anything about `.wrappedInstance`

Comment: Yeah, that wrappedInstance part was just something i noticed when i pulled up some of my old code that did this stuff. I may have been on an old version or doing something weird.

Answer (score 14):

An update to the accepted answer: `ref` and `getRef` both work, but only one will work depeneding on the wrapping component. In this case, my `<Input>` components are wrapped by an `<Item>` component, each with different `label` properties. Compare:

```
<Item floatingLabel>
  <Label>First Name</Label>
  <Input
    getRef={input => {
      this.firstNameRef = input;
    }}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
      this.lastNameRef._root.focus();
    }}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
  />
</Item>
```

And

```
<Item fixedLabel>
  <Label>First Name</Label>
  <Input
    ref={input => {
      this.lastNameRef = input;
    }}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
      this.lastNameRef._root.focus();
    }}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
  />
</Item>
```

In the case of `floatingLabel`, `getRef` works, while `ref` does not. On the other hand, in the case of `fixedLabel`, `ref` works, while `getRef` does not.

Not really to explain why, but maybe this caveat will help someone else in the future.

Comment: But I still not done... I have two input fields and a submit button, developing on android. <Enter> on first input focuses on the second. Is there a way to make enter in the second focus on the submit button? Otherwise, when the focus is on the 2nd input, the keyboard hides the submit button, and the only way to hide the keyboard is by clicking on the 'back' button

Comment: You can't really focus a button on mobile (at least I don't think you can, kinda doesn't make sense due to the lack of a cursor). The best you can do is set `returnKeyType={"done"}` on your last input, so pressing `<Enter>` or equivalent will auto-hide the keyboard.

Comment: @Yossi That being said, you may consider asking your own question with more details; might be able to get a better response.

Comment: And if you do not pass any arguments to `<Item>`, `ref` is the one that works.